# How send file with parameters to soapui

Tags: file, groovy, soapui

I'm testing webservice request with soapUi and need to send parameters to request, stored in config file.

Parameters are:

Key - static parameter, for access to webservice
Parameters 1-4 - dynamic, can change in config file and send to web-service again.

All parameters both Key and Parameters 1-3 I need send to soapui request as config file using groovy script.

Request to web-service like:

```html
<Header/>
       <Body>
             <request>
                   <accesskeytoservice>
                     <key>Key</key>
                   </accesskeytoservice>
                           <UseService> 
                           <parameter1>Parameter1<parameter1>
                           <parameter2>Parameter2<parameter2>
                           <parameter3>Parameter3<parameter3>
                           </UseService>                
             </request>
       </Body>
```

I had tried to store data in csv, txt and xml format and then read it to soapui request parsing data from file, but all tries still didn't work properly.

What format of config file is preferred in this case?

Answer (score 0):

How are you opening and reading your config file? Using Groovy? If you have successfully done that part the rest is simpler. Define two variables and use

```
context.setProperty(name,value)
```

Loop until eof.